# Error while syncing with Testnet, Invalid block

Tags: testnet

[image]

I have tried node version 1.30.01, 1.29. 1.29rc-2 .1.33 - latest
They all encounter this invalid block here.

I'm using config file for the testnet here https://hydra.iohk.io/build/7654130/download/1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest node and the latest configuration files.

The latest release can be found here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases

The config files for this release are here: https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html